# Datadog airflow alert when a dag is paused

Tags: airflow, devops, datadog

We have encountered a scenario recently where someone mistakenly turned off a production dag, and we want to get alert whenever a dag is paused using datadog.

I have checked https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/?tab=host

But have not got any metric for dag to check if it is paused or not.

I can run a custom script in datadog as well.

One of the method is that I exec into postgres pod and get the list of active dags:

```
select * from dag where is_paused=true;
```

Or is there any other way I can get the unpaused dag list and also when new dag is added what is the best way to handle it.

I want the alert whenever a unpaused dag is paused.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Airflow 2 you can use the REST API to query for state of the DAG.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag

There is "is_paused" field.

And of you are not Airflow 2, you should be. Airflow 1.10 is end-of-life and will not receive any fixes (including critical security fixes) so you should upgrade as soon as you can.